# Create Numpy array from list of arbitrary sized bites

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-random

How can I create a numpy array from a python list of bytes objects of an arbitrary (but known) size?

Example:

```
size = 10
byte_list = [np.random.default_rng().bytes(size) for i in range(100)]

numpy_array = # make array from byte_list

# do something with the array
test_vals = np.random.default_rng().choice(numpy_array, size=10)
```

I tried to do something like this, but got an error that it didn't understand 'B10' as a data type.

```
numpy_array = np.fromiter(byte_list, dtype=np.dtype(f'B{size}'), count=100)
```

Comment: What would you like the output to look like? What kind of shape?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs The output should just be a 1-D array

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [`S` dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.bytes_) and not `B`

```
numpy_array = np.fromiter(byte_list, dtype=np.dtype(f'S{size}'), count=100)
#                                              HERE --^
```

```
# Unsigned byte (only one)
>>> np.dtype('B')
dtype('uint8')

# Byte string
>>> np.dtype('S10')
dtype('S10')
```

Comment: This almost works, but since the S dtype is for a zero terminated string, if the value ends with \x00 it will get stripped off. I need the values in the array to be exactly the same as in the initial list.